# System.OutOfMemoryException thrown for large table in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This may be a simple or rapidly asked question.

In my EF application I am getting an exception.

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I am trying to retrieve records form **Log** table based on the **idList (int)**.
Logs table has millions of records. How to fix this exception or how to optimize the code to solve this?

```
    var resultList = idList.Join(clientEntities.Logs,
                                 x => x,
                                 s => s.ID,
                                 (x, s) => s)

    foreach (var r in resultList)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Exception was thrown while executing the loop.

Comment: `OutOfMemory` exceptions are extremely difficult to debug, particularly when we can't see what other code is being used. What's happening inside the `foreach`?

Comment: Is there an option for you to use paging ?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen- it is not even go inside the foreach.

Comment: I think the right suggestion is to use paging here. Limit your query by N (ie 1000) rows per call. Are you calling ToList() at the and of the query?

Comment: not guaranteed preventing memory exception, but it does improve performance, try `clientEntities.Logs.AsNoTracking()`

Answer (score -1):

I think best option for you is to use paging.You can limit the records by using paging.